# Woocommerce product page on mobile - "you may also like" stacking in one column wrongly

Tags: css, wordpress, mobile, woocommerce

If you view our product page on mobile ...

https://www.charliecustards.co.uk/product/the-charlie-montreux-brogue-chelsea-boot-in-autumn-calf-leather/

... and scroll down to the "you may also like" section you will see it is not in rows of two products, as it should be. It is in one column stacked with a big white space down the side of each item in the stack where it clearly should be placing the other product.

What is the code so it shows two products next to each other (rows of two) when this section stacks on mobile? I've tried everything under the sun and can't get it to co-operate!

Also see screen capture which shows the issue clearly. Thank you so much all!

[image: screen capture of incorrect mobile stacking on woocommerce you may also like section of a product page]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently have this code:

```
.woocommerce ul.products li.product, .woocommerce-page ul.products li.product, .woocommerce .related ul.products li.product, .woocommerce-page .related ul.products li.product, .woocommerce .upsells.products ul.products li.product, .woocommerce-page .upsells.products ul.products li.product, .woocommerce[class*=columns-] ul.products li.product, .woocommerce-page[class*=columns-] ul.products li.product {
    float: none!important;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    max-width: 280px;
    text-align: center;
    width: auto;
}
```

You have to change it to:

```
.woocommerce ul.products li.product, .woocommerce-page ul.products li.product, .woocommerce .related ul.products li.product, .woocommerce-page .related ul.products li.product, .woocommerce .upsells.products ul.products li.product, .woocommerce-page .upsells.products ul.products li.product, .woocommerce[class*=columns-] ul.products li.product, .woocommerce-page[class*=columns-] ul.products li.product {
    float: none;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    max-width: 280px;
    text-align: center;
    width: auto;
}
```

You have to remove the **`!important`** rule from the `float` property.

Comment: Hi

Thank you for the response and help. I put that code in the additional CSS and unfortunately it did not change? Its still the same.

Comment: If you are using a cache plugin, clear the cache.

Comment: Hi Thank you, I cleared the website cache via our cache plugin and still has not changed on mobile? Thank you for your help so far, really appreacite it. :)

Comment: Have you checked that there are no other rules after the following that override it? Remove the current rule and add it to the end of the css file. It has to work. Alternatively, you could remove the `float: none;` line entirely.

Comment: Thank you this worked as you said. I got it to work by deleting the !important directly from    the woocomerce css file in the theme editor rather than trying to do it from the custom css. Once i took it directly out the code in the theme editor it worked. Thank you. How do i give you a positive rating!? :)

Comment: Sent you a coffee ;)